# convert if-else statement inside a cursor in a set-based approach

Tags: sql, t-sql, cursor, set-based

I have a script containing a cursor with if-else statement, but it takes too much times to browse the table. (a table with 79000 rows takes 1h). 
So i need to convert it in a set-based approach.

The if statement is

```
IF  ( 
        SELECT  count (b.key) 
          FROM general..ean a,
               general..mainframe b,
               general..hope c 
        WHERE a.ean = @ean
        AND a.c_suppression = '0' 
        AND a.key = b.key           
        AND b.key = c.key
        AND c.canal = @canal
    ) = 0
```

where @ean and @canal are value retrieved in each row with the cursor. The table browsed is tmp_day_house_info_corporate.
So i need to retrieve all rows from tmp_day_house_info_corporate, for which @info and @canal in the if statement retrieve 0.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you post whole code including cursor declaration and fetching?

Comment: I suspect you may want to rewrite the cursor iteration as a join, but without seeing more of the code, it's hard to do more than micro optimize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    SELECT  *
      FROM tmp_day_house_info_corporate
    WHERE not exists(
        SELECT  b.key
          FROM general..ean a,
               general..mainframe b,
               general..hope c 
        WHERE a.ean = tmp_day_house_info_corporate.ean
        AND a.c_suppression = '0' 
        AND a.key = b.key           
        AND b.key = c.key
        AND c.canal = tmp_day_house_info_corporate.canal
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

`Count` is highly ineffective when checking if record exists, you would be much better with `not exists`

```
IF NOT EXISTS  ( 
        SELECT * 
          FROM general..ean a,
               general..mainframe b,
               general..hope c 
        WHERE a.ean = @ean
        AND a.c_suppression = '0' 
        AND a.key = b.key           
        AND b.key = c.key
        AND c.canal = @canal
    )
```

If this is till to slow show your full query and maybe it will be possible to make it set-based.

Comment: Small note: `TOP 1` is not needed with `NOT EXISTS`. Scan(or Seek) stops on the first row that matches the criteria and return false.